# Avoid rerender on mouse move

Tags: reactjs

Is there an easy way of avoid rerendering of context on mouse move like the example provided. I need a static page and it translates through style and mouse position, but I do not need to rerender it each time, just once.

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-cache-ygt8r

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You're rendering the mouse coordinates, so naturally you need to re-render when they change?!

Answer (score 0):

You can optimise on re-renders by throttling your mouse move handler

```
const handleMouseMove = useCallback(
    _.throttle((e) => {
      setMouse((state) => ({
        ...state,
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY
      }));
    }, 300),
    []
  );
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-river-4bhm3?file=/src/App.js)